# Android getting Strange Box Symbol

Tags: java, android, string

I am getting a bunch of information from a database. To make sure various symbols work I am testing with the String below.

```
awdasdasdada
sa 
asdasd                     
asdasdasd!Q&amp;#^@)#^@)#_@*#&amp;@&amp;#
(!@&amp;#*(@T$#&amp;^$#
^*%$#^$^#@*&amp;^*
```

I set this String to one of my TextView's text and get the following result.
[image]

The box symbols do not show up in the String, yet they are displayed. Anyone have any idea what those strange symbols are and how to get rid of them?

Comment: Could be an encoding problem. But without your code, we wont be able to help.

Comment: usually a box indicates a character that the system doesn't know how to display.

Comment: I will provide some more information about my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Android are you testing this on? If it's 2.1 then it might be that you're getting `\n\r` from the database. For some reason, 2.1 displays `\r` as those boxes. You have to remove all of the `\r`s from the string if you want to preserve new lines when using 2.1.

Comment: I am using a scanner like so 
Scanner in = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))
     .useDelimiter("\\|");
Is there a way to remove the /r before the scanning begins?

Comment: No, but you can either strip them out as you are reading them, or you can remove them when the whole stream has been read.